# JavaScript - How to show interface suggestions for every typing

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, webstorm

Hello I'm newbie at JavaScript and I wan to create a interface but the interface's variable's name is not gonna be a fix name. So the Interface have to return the suggestions for every name that I write.

Inside of my Interface file:

```
export interface ArchiveData {
  id: string;
  latest_reel_media: number;
  seen?: any;
  ...
}

export interface Reels {
  anyArchiveName: ArchiveData;
}

export interface ArchivedStoryDataResponse {
  reels: Reels;
  status: string;
}
```

The result with fixed name:

[image: The result with fixed name]

The result with another name; no suggestions:

[image: The result with another name; no suggestions]

Comment: Please check if the new `typescript` tag is correct. You may also want to add a tag for your IDE if the code is run as a command to set up an interface in the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's been a long time but I finally reached my goal

```
export interface ArchiveData {
  id: string;
  latest_reel_media: number;
  seen?: any;
  ...
}

export interface Reels {
  [reel_id:string]: ArchiveData;// this line
}

export interface ArchivedStoryDataResponse {
  reels: Reels;
  status: string;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]